# GL_BLEND not drawing JAVA

Tags: java, opengl, blend

I'm currently making a method to draw a simple rectangle in my game in Java. It works fine when I simply use this code:

```
    glPushMatrix();     

    glColor4f(red,green,blue,alpha);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x, y+y1);
        glVertex2f(x+x1, y+y1);
        glVertex2f(x+x1, y);
    }
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
```

But when I try to enable GL_BLEND for transperency,

```
    glPushMatrix();

    glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glColor4f(red,green,blue,alpha);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x, y+y1);
        glVertex2f(x+x1, y+y1);
        glVertex2f(x+x1, y);
    }
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    glPopMatrix();
```

The rectangle doesn't draw.

Comment: What is the value of `alpha`?  `0.5`?

Comment: you don't have mendled with glAlphaFunc beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

If `alpha` is `0.0` your quad will be fully transparent.  Set it to something like `0.5`.

And as cfrick pointed out make sure you disable alpha testing via `glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)`.

Example:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

bool blend = false;
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    if( key == 'b' )
    {
        blend = !blend;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisable( GL_BLEND );
    if( blend )
    {
        glEnable( GL_BLEND );
        glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    }

    glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f );
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glVertex2i( -1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1, -1 );
    glVertex2i(  1,  1 );
    glVertex2i( -1,  1 );
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the C++, I'm not much of a Java guy.  The GL command sequencing should be the same either way though.